# XmlInclude for derived class with no acess to base class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a derived class which only adds methods to the base class and I would like to serialize it as its base class, the issue i am having is that this is for a game mod and I can't modify the base class directly to add the XmlInclude to the base.

```
namespace CustomNPC
{
public class CustomNPCInteract : NPC
{
public CustomNPCInteract()
  :base()
{
  this.initializeNPC();
}

public CustomNPCInteract(AnimatedSprite sprite, Vector2 position, string defaultMap, int facingDir, string name, bool dateable, Dictionary<int, int[]> schedule, Texture2D portrait)
  : base(sprite, position, defaultMap, facingDir, name, dateable, schedule, portrait)
{
  this.initializeNPC();
}

public CustomNPCInteract(AnimatedSprite sprite, Vector2 position, int facingDir, string name, StardewValley.LocalizedContentManager manager = null)
  :base(sprite, position, facingDir, name, manager)
{
  this.initializeNPC();
}

private void initializeNPC()
{
  this.age = 2; //child
  this.manners = 2; //rude
  this.socialAnxiety = 1; //shy
  this.optimism = 1; //negative
  this.gender = 1; //female
  this.datable = false; //not-datable
  this.homeRegion = 0; //Other
  this.birthday_Season = "fall"; //fall 8
  this.birthday_Day = 8;
    }
}
}
```

Is how my namespace and class are setup. CustomNPCInteract inherits NPC and I would like it to serialize like any other NPC but without access to modify that specific class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it...

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomNPCInteract),new XmlRootAttribute("NPC"));
```

This will rename the root of the serialized XML to NPC so then you can use standard deserialization

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The actual game I am writing the mod for already has its own serializer instance under SaveGame.serializer which it uses to save data. Is there away to append to it instead of overwriting their existing instance?

Comment: No. You will have to override it.  XML does not lend itself to appending data since there is at most one root node in any XML document.  It should be a simple matter to replace the default serializer with your own but without know more I cannot make any further suggestions.